# Compare a string with a lookup table and perform replacement

Tags: python, pandas

I want to iterate over a string of values in a Python `dataframe` and compare each value in that string with keys in a lookup table. If it matches, we replace with the value from the lookup table.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
index   String
1       ['a','b','c']
2       ['d','e','f','g','h']
3       ['i','j']
```

The lookup table looks like this:

```
key  value
---  -----
a    apple
b    book
c    clock
d    duck
e    else
f    far
g    girl
h    hour
i    ink
j    juice
```

The expected result should look like this:

```
index   String
1      ['apple','book','clock']
2      ['duck','else','far','girl','hour']
3      ['ink','juice']
```

I know that i should use `isin()` function to check if a value from the first column exists but have now idea how to do the replacement. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see others have beaten me to post answers but, so far, neither takes account of the scenario that the string might not be in the lookup table, which you have mentioned in your question. The below code uses a conditional check as to whether the string is in the lookup table and leaves the string unchanged if it is not present.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"String": [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j'], ['k', 'l']]})
lookup = {'a': 'apple',
          'b': 'book',
          'c': 'clock',
          'd': 'duck',
          'e': 'else',
          'f': 'far',
          'g': 'girl',
          'h': 'hour',
          'i': 'ink',
          'j': 'juice'}

df['String'] = df['String'].apply(lambda string: [lookup[val] if val in lookup else val for val in string])
```

Result:

```
                          String
0           [apple, book, clock]
1  [duck, else, far, girl, hour]
2                   [ink, juice]
3                         [k, l]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'String': [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f','g','h'], ['i','j']]})

mymap = {
'a':   'apple',
'b':    'book',
'c':    'clock',
'd':    'duck',
'e':    'else',
'f':    'far',
'g':    'girl',
'h':    'hour',
'i':    'ink',
'j':    'juice'
}

df['String'] = df['String'].apply(lambda x: [mymap.get(i) for i in x])

df
```

Output:

```
                          String
0           [apple, book, clock]
1  [duck, else, far, girl, hour]
2                   [ink, juice]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
my_dict=pd.Series(lookuptable.value.values,index=lookuptable.key).to_dict()
df.String=df.String.apply(lambda x:[my_dict[i] for i in x])
```

Answer (score 1):

This list comprehension should work if the lookup table is a dataframe:

```
df['String'].apply(lambda x: [z2 for y in x for z1, z2 in zip(df1['key'], df1['value']) if y == z1])
```

See the full code below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
 'String': {0: "['a','b','c']", 1: "['d','e','f','g','h']", 2: "['i','j']"}})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': {0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c',
  3: 'd',
  4: 'e',
  5: 'f',
  6: 'g',
  7: 'h',
  8: 'i',
  9: 'j'},
 'value': {0: 'apple',
  1: 'book',
  2: 'clock',
  3: 'duck',
  4: 'else',
  5: 'far',
  6: 'girl',
  7: 'hour',
  8: 'ink',
  9: 'juice'}})

df2 = df.copy()    
df2['String'] = df['String'].replace(['\[','\]', '\''], '', regex=True).str.split(',')
df2['String'] = df2['String'].apply(lambda x: [z2 for y in x for z1, z2 in zip(df1['key'], df1['value']) if y == z1])
# df2['String'] = df2['String'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
df2
Out[1]: 
   index                         String
0      1           [apple, book, clock]
1      2  [duck, else, far, girl, hour]
2      3                   [ink, juice]
```

Comment: df2 is not defined

Comment: @Taie fixed this.